# Upper bound the measure of a set

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

My question is taken from section 1.2 of [this book](https://www.hse.ru/data/2016/11/24/1113029206/Concentration%20inequalities.pdf). Specifically, given a probability measure $\mathbf{P}$ on a metric space $\mathcal X$ (which is equipped with the metric $d$) and suppose that $X$ is a random variable taking values in $\mathcal X$ with distribution $\mathbf{P}$. The authors claimed that we have $$\mathbf{P}\left(\{x \in \mathcal{X} \colon f(x) \leq \mathbb{E} f(X)\right) \geq \frac 12,$$ where $f \colon \mathcal{X} \to \mathbb R$ is $1$-Lipschitz, i.e., $|f(x) - f(y)| \leq d(x,y)$ for all $x,y \in \mathcal{X}$. May I know how this inequality is derived? I tried a routine Markov's inequality but this inequality seems to be useless for this problem and I am really curious as to where does the $\frac 12$ come from.

Comment: Yo did not say what $f$ is . The inequality is false in general.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy sorry, I have edited the question!

Comment: Take $f(x) = x$, $P\{1\} = 0.1, P\{9\} = 0.9$. Then $Ef = 0.91$ but the measure of $f(x) \le Ef$ is $0.1$.

Comment: Exsitence of $Ef(X)$ is not guaranteed under the gievn conditions.

Comment: @copper.hat So the book contains a "bug"?

Comment: I don't know, I did not read the book.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy If you look at their book that's what is stated on paper (I also bought the real book it is stated in this way as well...)

Comment: @copper.hat Thank you very much anyway!

Comment: @FeiCao Perhaps there is some relationship between the metric and measure?

Comment: @copper.hat From my understanding, the authors didn't mention such a relation unfortunately... what if we restrict the measure to be atomless? Does the conclusion hold in that case?

Comment: I did not see anything like that in the book. In Section 1.2, they are looking at deviation from the median, not the expectation.

Comment: The “median” just means “expectation”.

Comment: Well, no. The median is defined e.g. in exercise 2.1

Comment: @md5 thank you for pointing this out! This is ridiculous as the authors are using notations from Chapter 2 in Chapter 1 without any "forward referencing"...